# Weird behaviour in SharePoint search

Tags: search

I have a created a lot of lists connected to each other:

... <- ... <- Product Family <- Product Type <- Product Code <- Claim

For instance Claim List looks like this:

- Claim Key
- Product Code Reference (Product Code List)
- ...

Then I have created two content types as documents (PDF), Claim Document and Communication Document, both related to the Claim List.

Claim Document Content Type looks like this (same for Communication Document):

- Claim Key Reference (Claim List)
- ...

Now I'd like **search** to work in a certain way but it doesn't. For instance if I search for Claim Key all the related PDF Claim Documents appear in the result. However if I search for Product Code the related Claim List is shown while the PDF Documents are not. It's like search only works for one level reference but not up to that. Am I missing something? I am a newbie about SharePoint so forgive me if something is not explained correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is pretty in depth in terms of what you will need to do, but at a high level you should take a look at Search Scopes and Search metadata properties.

Scopes allow you to pinpoint your searches to a more granular level so you can tell it to only return results back for a particular content type such as your claim document content type.

Metadata properties allows you to setup specific columns such as the claim Key as a field that you can search against directly.

To get started I suggest you take a look at these links:

[Technet - Metadata Properties](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621097%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

[Technet - Search Scopes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792872%28v=office.14%29.aspx)